# .toggle not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, toggle

For some reason this doesn't always work in safari and functions even less on the iPad, any guesses?  =(

```
$(".dropdown .sub").click(function () {
     $("#menu .holder").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Without the context of your HTML or other javascript it's impossible to say. However, what you've got in your question should work without any issues.

Comment: @markp see http://jsfiddle.net/rCN9n/1/ - that's some very basic markup and your jQuery. The jQuery is fine, so it's impossible to tell what's causing your issues without knowing more info.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't know context might be the issue, [here is a link to the site](http://www.ielectronics.com).

Comment: @markp a link to the site isn't enough, you need to add code that would recreate the issue in your question so that you question will be useful after your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the web page provided It appears that the toggle selector has many children.  Something like this:

```
<div id="menu" class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li class="level1">
            <a class="sub" href="#"><strong>TV &amp; Video</strong></a>
            <div class="holder">HOLDER</div>
        </li>
        <li class="level1">
            <a class="sub" href="#"><strong>TV &amp; Video</strong></a>
            <div class="holder">HOLDER</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will not work:

```
$(".dropdown .sub").click(function () {
     $("#menu .holder").toggle();
});
```

You will need to find the first sibling element.

```
$(".dropdown .sub").click(function () {
     $(this).siblings(".holder").eq(0).toggle();
});
```

Find a jsfiddle of this here ->http://jsfiddle.net/rCN9n/5/

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't know context might be the issue, [here is a link to the site](http://www.ielectronics.com).

Comment: Unfortunately the dropdown stops working when I change .click to .change   =(

Comment: I updated the fiddle above to use your markup. click method still works.  [http://jsfiddle.net/rCN9n/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/rCN9n/2/)

Comment: I think I see the problem.  You have many many elements that match $('#menu .holder')  You will need to make the holders unique or use a jquery ":first-child" selector.

Comment: Okay.  I got it!  Here is the magic jquery sauce: `$(".dropdown .sub").click(function () {
     $(this).siblings(".holder").eq(0).toggle();
});`  I updated the above jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/rCN9n/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/rCN9n/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much Rod, you truly are awesome! I'm too new with jQuery to have ever figured that out!   =)