# Why "use strict"; prevent a jQuery click event on Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, click, use-strict

My jQuery click event **does not work** when I use the "strict mode" in my external javascript file. The "use strict"; is placed on top of the file.

However, the click event **does works** when using the script in the head of the file.

The version of safari is 601.1 and ios 9.3.3

[Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) seems to have advantages regarding *standardisation* and *long term stability* of the code. So, I guess it's the way to go.

This issue of Safari and jQuery click event happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255809/toggle-not-working-in-safari) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios) etc.

If possible, I'd like to keep using the strict mode. Thanks

The script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    [ A lot of code here ];

    function addMoreInfoBtnToggle() {
        $("#addMoreInfoBtn").toggle();
        $(".addMoreInfo").toggle();
    }       
    var addMoreInfoBtn_clicked = $("#addMoreInfoBtn_clicked").val();
    if(addMoreInfoBtn_clicked === '1'){addMoreInfoBtnToggle();}
    $("#addMoreInfoBtn").click( function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault;
        addMoreInfoBtnToggle();
        $("#addMoreInfoBtn_clicked").val('1');
    });
});
```

Comment: Which safari version you are using ? It will support  Safari from version 5.1.+

Comment: I edited. Safari 601.1 on ios 9.3.3